# Is it possible to create a count that restarts every day?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm aiming to create a restaurant point of sales, which will display features such as calculating total revenue by seeing the prices of the orders that come through. With this, I also want to create a count that shows total daily revenue, meaning it will restart at 12am every day. Is this possible?

Currently, my code for revenue is just using application settings.

```
label2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.totalRev.ToString();


Program.total = Program.total + Program.sumTot;
Properties.Settings.Default.totalRev = Program.total;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

`sumTot` is the new price being added to the current overall revenue (`Program.total`)

Comment: Schedule a timer to call `Properties.Settings.Default.totalRev = 0`

Comment: I wouldn't use settings for actual variables you need in your form. You should make your form stand-alone and should only use settings to **set** itself up. ***You should show us your full code***.

Comment: Why not just query your database to return a sum where dates fall in expected range?

Comment: You've posted identical code yesterday, for another question that isn't directly related to that code. Settings aren't data or counters. If you want to store a count for every day, write it to a file or database. Not the user settings. If you want to count orders/amounts by day, you can write orders to a different file for each day. Or you can use a single table in a database to store each order with its date and then calculate the SUM by date with `SELECT date, SUM(Total) FROM Orders GROUP BY Date;`

Comment: yes- this seems like a very lazy question. "restaurant point of sales" so there are orders..? where are they stored?

Comment: Could you update the question with how you Order object looks like and if it has a parent object that contains collection of Orders? Also tell where are you storing the data

Comment: You definitely need some sort of database to store your data. You need to design one that fits your needs. You can start with SQL Server express since it is free to use even in commercial environments.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best `sum` the days data in a database query to support multiple users.

However, if you want to keep it to the C# code you could store the current day in a variable and only update the summed total if the day has not changed. If it has changed then just use the total as it is.

```
if(currentDay == DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
{
   Program.total = Program.total + Program.sumTot;
}else{
   currentDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear
}
Properties.Settings.Default.totalRev = Program.total;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You may need to save this beyond a variable if you have multiple systems or the app restarts. Also, note that DateTime.Now is using the apps timezone which may or may not be correct depending on your usecase.